# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableEveryone: true});
```

Something wrong should be on this line. But it doesnt look wrong to me.. If you need more code to tell whats wrong tell me. Thanks

Comment: How did you import `discord` package? And you can add `console.log(Discord)` to check what it is

Comment: `const {Collection, Client, Discord} = require('discord.js');` you mean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

discord.js does not export `Discord` so the solution above should solve this.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

const myCollection = new Discord.Collection();
```

^ This should work. Anymore problems? Comment and I'll try help